# Looking for an online Yu-Gi-Oh! game where you can add your real life deck

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Is there a Yu-Gi-Oh! game in which you can input the card number you have in real life and build your own deck online according to the cards you have in real life?

I remember seeing an old version of Yu-Gi-Oh! that was able to do that. It was a portable console device back then. I'm just wondering if there is an updated version for cards today in the present with these new rules and etc., where you can input your cards numbers online, and it will appear as that specific card you inputted. Then you can make a deck with those cards and test it online with friends.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there's not an official game that will let you do this. Back in the day, letting the player just input the card ID of the real card and having it appear in-game was fine, but charging you money for virtual packs is much more profitable now.

If you want to play yugioh online and want to use your own cards, stuff like YGOPro is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score -2):

Try using yugioh! NEXUS. You can input the name of the card and then put it in your deck. You will have to log in.